# How to emit an infinite stream of numbers every second in nodejs using sockets and then receive them on an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I want to emit an infinite stream of numbers using nodejs and web sockets (preferably socket.io) in the back end server and then receive them on an html page using javascript. What would be the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This will create an infinite loop on the server which is probably not the best idea lol, so feel free to rework that to whatever fits your needs.

`server`

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  while (true) {
    // generate random integer up to 100
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100))
    socket.emit('newNumber', { number: num });
  }
});
```

`client`

```
 const socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('newNumber', (data) => {
    // do whatever you want with the number
    console.log(data);
  });
```